# Standard Error and confidence interval for multiple linear regression in matrix notation

Tags: regression, linear

Lets say we are trying to fit a normal linear model to our data as follows:

$y = \beta _0 + x_1\beta_1 + x_2\beta_2 + ... + x_p\beta_p  + \epsilon$.

My question is that how we can derive the standard error and confidence interval for each of the coefficient in matrix notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the usual Normal Gauss-Markov Model where $\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{X\beta}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, it is assummed $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\sim N\left(0,\boldsymbol{I}\sigma^{2}\right)$, where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix, where $n$ is the number of observations in your dataset. This implies $Var(\boldsymbol{Y})=Var\left(\boldsymbol{X\beta}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\right)=Var(\boldsymbol{\epsilon})=\boldsymbol{I}\sigma^{2}$.Then, under this model:

\begin{eqnarray*}
Var\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) & = & Var\left[\boldsymbol{\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-}X^{\prime}Y}\right]\\
 & = & Var\left[\boldsymbol{AY}\right]\\
 & = & \boldsymbol{A}Var(\boldsymbol{Y})\boldsymbol{A^{\prime}}\\
 & = & \boldsymbol{A}\left(\boldsymbol{I}\sigma^{2}\right)\boldsymbol{A}^{\prime}\\
 & = & \left[\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\right]\left(\boldsymbol{I}\sigma^{2}\right)\left[\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\right]^{\prime}\\
 & = & \sigma^{2}\left[\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}\right]\left[\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right]\left[\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}\right]\\
 & = & \sigma^{2}\boldsymbol{I}\left[\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}\right]\\
 & = & \sigma^{2}\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}
\end{eqnarray*}

Normally we don't know $\sigma^{2}$ so it has to estimated from the residuals, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\epsilon}}$ to give us:   $Var\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\right)=\hat{\sigma}^{2}\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-}$. Without getting into all the gory details, the estimated $\sigma^2$ is given by: $$\hat{\sigma}^{2}=\frac{\hat{\epsilon}^{\prime}\hat{\epsilon}}{n-r}$$
where $n$ is the number of rows in $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $r$ is
the rank of $\boldsymbol{X}$.

Then, again, without going into all the distribution derivations and other gory details, 
the $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $\hat{\beta}_{j}$,
$j=0,1,\ldots,k,$ ($k=r-1$) is given by:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{\beta}_{j} & \pm & t_{\alpha/2,n-r}\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{g_{jj}}
\end{eqnarray*}

where $g_{jj}$ is the $j$th diagonal element of $\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-}$,
and $t_{\alpha/2,n-r}$ is the $\left(\alpha/2\right)100$ percentile
of the $t$-distribution, with $n-r$ degrees of freedom.

Here is an example of the computations done manually and then checked against confidence intervals computed by R:

```
> library(MASS)
> 
> ##create some data
> data("mtcars")
> y<-mtcars$mpg
> y
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3
[27] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
> x0<-rep(1, dim(mtcars)[1])
> x1<-mtcars$disp
> x2<-mtcars$hp
> x3<-mtcars$drat
> X<-cbind(x0, x1, x2, x3)
> 
> ##print first rows of design matrix X
> head(X)
     x0  x1  x2   x3
[1,]  1 160 110 3.90
[2,]  1 160 110 3.90
[3,]  1 108  93 3.85
[4,]  1 258 110 3.08
[5,]  1 360 175 3.15
[6,]  1 225 105 2.76
> 
> ##calculate beta hats - note:  not efficient, just for teaching
> beta.hat<-ginv(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%y
> beta.hat
            [,1]
[1,] 19.34429256
[2,] -0.01923223
[3,] -0.03122932
[4,]  2.71497521
> ##get predicted values
> y.hat <- X%*%beta.hat
> residuals <- y-y.hat
> ##find n and rank, r
> r <- qr(X)$rank
> n <- dim(X)[1]
> ##compute covariance matrix
> var.beta.hat <- as.numeric(t(residuals)%*%residuals/(n - r))*ginv(t(X)%*%X)
> ##compute confidence interval
> alpha <- .05
> t <-qt(1 - alpha/2, n - r)
> conf.int <- round(cbind(beta.hat - t*sqrt(diag(var.beta.hat)), beta.hat + t*sqrt(diag(var.beta.hat))), 5)
> conf.int
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  6.29413 32.39445
[2,] -0.03843 -0.00004
[3,] -0.05857 -0.00389
[4,] -0.33176  5.76171
> 
> #fit model with standard R lm package
> r.fit <-lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
> #show confidence intervals in R
> round(confint(r.fit, names(r.fit$coef), level = 0.95), 5)
               2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept)  6.29413 32.39445
x1          -0.03843 -0.00004
x2          -0.05857 -0.00389
x3          -0.33176  5.76171
```

**Update 1. to Assist With Your Additional Comment/Question About the Standard Error**

@prony, so we are trying to calculate the standard error, so I'm not sure what you mean by the standard error is defined as $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$   But I think I understand your question.  To understand where $\sqrt{g_{jj}}$ is coming from, first, notice that the standard error is just the square root of the variance of an estimator -- in this case, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$.  So really, all we are trying to do is obtain the square root of each of the diagonal elements of $Var(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}) = \hat{\sigma}^2(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{X})^-$.  Here, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ is a vector.  So to obtain the standard error for a single $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$, (what I call $\hat{\beta_j}$ and note this is not longer bolded as it's just a single element), we need to pick off the element corresponding to the $j$th row and $j$th column of the $\hat{\sigma}^2(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{X})^-$ matrix, and take the square root of it (this amounts to taking the square root of the diagonal entries of the matrix, which are the variances before square-rooting. The off-diagonal entries are the covariances).  I have simply defined $\sqrt{g_{jj}}$ to be equal to the $j$th diagonal element of the square matrix $(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{X})^-$ so that when we obtain the square root of the diagonal element of $\hat{\sigma}^2(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{X})^-$ to obtain the standard error, we get $\sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2g_{jj}}=\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{g_{jj}}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I was mostly interested in the gory details since I wanted to get the derivation. I found the derivation for estimation $\hat{\sigma}$. However, i could not understand why standar error of the estimator of a coefficient is $\hat{\sigma}\sqrt(g_{jj})$.

Comment: No problem.  Do you mean you are confused how we get $\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{g_{jj}}$ as the standard error of a coefficient or did you mean to say that you are wanting to understand how it is that we determine  $\frac{\hat{\beta}_{j}}{\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{g_{jj}}}$ is distributed as a central $t$ distribution?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question. I meant the first one. Because, to the best of my knowledge (forgive my ignorance), the standard error is defined as $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. I understand here we use estimator for the sigma but I don't understand where the $\sqrt{g_{jj}}$ is coming from. Btw, the reason why $\frac{\hat{\beta}}{\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{g_{jj}}}$ follows t distribution is that $\hat{\beta}$ is normally distributed and $\hat{\sigma}$ follow chi-square distribution right?

Comment: @prony, I just added "Update 1" at the end of the question to address  your additional question about the derivation of the standard error.  Is that clear now?

Comment: Also, @prony, the distribution is $t$ because (1) $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\sim N_r[\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma^2(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{X})^-]$, (2) $(n-r)\hat{\sigma}^2/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_{n-r}$ and (3) $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I am accepting it.

Comment: Thanks, @prony.  By the way, if you are interested in a really nice reference for these types of derivations, I would recommend you check out Linear Models in Statistics, 2nd ed. by Rencher and Schaalje, 2007. It's a great reference.

Answer (score 2):

Estimate the covariance matrix of the coefficients via

$$ \widehat{\bf{\Sigma}} = \hat{\sigma}^2(X'X)^{-1} $$

The diagonal elements are the variances

$$ \operatorname{diag}(\widehat{\Sigma)} = \left[ \hat{\sigma}^2_0, \dots, \hat{\sigma}_p^2 \right]$$

Here,

$$\hat{\sigma}^2_j = \hat{\sigma}^2 (X'X)^{-1}_{jj} $$

Though it isn't typical to write the square root of a vector, let $\sqrt{ \operatorname{diag}(\widehat{\Sigma)}}$ be the diagonal of $\widehat{\Sigma}$ where each component has been square rooted.

I suppose the confidence intervals are then

$$ \beta\pm t_{1-\alpha/2, n-q-1}\sqrt{ \operatorname{diag}(\widehat{\Sigma)}}$$

Let's try it in R

```
#model
set.seed(0)
x = rnorm(9)
y = 2*x+1 +rnorm(9)
model = lm(y~x)

sigma = vcov(model)
tr.sigma = diag(sigma)

betas = coef(model)

#right
betas + qt(0.975,model$df.residual)*sqrt(tr.sigma)

Intercept)           x 
   1.859659    3.059125 

#left
betas - qt(0.975,model$df.residual)*sqrt(tr.sigma)

(Intercept)           x 
 0.01696051  1.17202056 

confint(model)
                2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.01696051 1.859659
x           1.17202056 3.059125
```

EDIT:  Faraway examines this very question on pg. 38 of *Linear Models With R*.  Link [here](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/books/LinearModelsWithR.pdf)

Comment: Can you explain why the trace of the square root of the matrix equals to the standard error?

Comment: How is the trace a vector as you have it defined?  The trace is a scalar since it's the sum of diagonal elements.

Comment: @StatsStudent Its been a long time since I've done linear algebra.  I think I just meant $\operatorname{diag}$

Comment: @StatsStudent  I've made some edits, which should now agree with the R code I've presented.

Comment: That's looking better, but while your ultimate confidence interval formula is correct, the RHS of your penultimate equation is not:  the $diag(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}) \ne \left[ \sigma^2_0, \dots, \sigma_p^2 \right]$.  How did your $(X'X)^{-1}$ term vanish?

Comment: @StatsStudent Were you expecting something like $ \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{(X'X)^{-1}_{jj} }$ as the elements of $\operatorname{diag}(\Sigma)$? I've just gotten sloppy and not explicitly written that $\sigma_j = \hat{\sigma}\sqrt{(X'X)^{-1}_{jj}}$

Comment: Yes, @DemetriPananos.  You've got it.  Although, it's probably better to write, $ \operatorname{diag}(\widehat{\Sigma)} = \left[ \hat{\sigma}_1(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime  \boldsymbol{X}_{11})^{-1/2}, \hat{\sigma}_2(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime  \boldsymbol{X}_{22})^{-1/2},\dots, \hat{\sigma}_p(\boldsymbol{X}^\prime  \boldsymbol{X}_{pp})^{-1/2}\right]$.  I hate to be so nit-picky on the notation, but for new learners, it's imperative, lest we cause more confusion.

Comment: @StatsStudent You're right, I should have been more explicit. I'll add a correction now.

Comment: No worries, at all @DemetriPananos.  In fact, I think some commentary back and forth about notation can actually be instructive to the OP.  Thanks for your contribution!